# Manipulate main frame from iFrame with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am cheating a bit with iFrames to create an illusion of AJAX-uploading. When the upload is complete I need to communicate information about the file that was uploaded to the main frame and list it.

If I have the following UL in the main frame and a JS-variable in the iFrame named filename, how can I append file_name to the list?

```
<ul id="uploaded_files">
  <li>My_file_name.jpg</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on where jQuery is loaded:

```
// jQuery is in the parent window
parent.$('#uploaded_files').append('<li/>').text(filename);
```

or

```
// jQuery is in the iframe
$('#uploaded_files', parent).append('<li/>').text(filename);
```